# ¿Cómo cerrar todos los ficheros abiertos en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Estoy usando **Visual Studio Code**, versión **1.28.2**.

Lo que quisiera es ***cerrar el conjunto de archivos abiertos de una sóla vez***, no ir uno a uno. No encuentro esta opción en el editor.

He estado mirando los menús, e hice una búsqueda en Internet. No encontre nada. Aquí están los [atajos de teclado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn320181.aspx) y tampoco aparece.

Comment: Click derecho sobre el nombre y Cerrar Todo o CTRL+K W

Comment: Muchas gracias @Aitor. Perfecto es justo lo que andaba buscando.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Click derecho sobre el nombre y `Cerrar Todo`.
2. Combinación de teclas: `CTRL+K W`